# Error: "Undefined variable: abstract"

Tags: python, pydev, abstract

I am extending some code for an online class.  There are a bunch of abstract methods defined as follows:

```
def aMethod(self):
    abstract
```

The code executes correctly, but PyDev is reporting the following error:

`Undefined variable: abstract`

It's doing so every time it encounters the abstract word.  What's going on here?

Comment: @randomhuman sorry, I figured out the solution while writing the question.  As a result, I spaced out and forgot to paste the code.  See edit.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes your own answer much clearer! If the errors shown in PyDev are annoying you, you can control whether they are shown as error, warnings, or not at all, in the preferences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume what's happening here is that the original developer is shoehorning abstract methods into the language by trying to reference an undefined symbol named `abstract`, which if called and not overridden, will cause a run-time error.

Comment: Why is an odd way to do it. Usually you would do something like `raise NotImplementedError`.